# Set link target depending on zone

Tags: 2010, navigation, web-application-zones

Background:
We have a SharePoint 2010 with two web applications. One contains our portal site collection and the other contains the My Sites.
The web application containing our portal site runs on port 80 and is accessible via http (http://portal.company.com) from within our local company network. This web application has been extended to port 443 to be accessible from outside our local company network via https (https://portal.company.com). AAMs have been set accordingly. This works fine so far.

My Question: On the My Sites we have added a navigation link back to our portal site. How can we forward the user to the correct URL depending on the user's zone (http://portal.company.com or https://portal.company.com)?

Thanks a lot in advance for your suppport!